# An unexpected warning while opening C file using gedit after compiling it

Tags: linux

I have made a game with game.c file. After that I have made a Makefile for compiling the game. By writing "make" in Terminal, the game compiles, and I can run the game also. But when I re-open the game.c-file with "gedit game.c" I get a warning :

> ** (gedit:5242): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-32NmbcAsWU: Connection refused

Although my c-file gets opened, I get this warning. How can I fix this warning? :/ :(

Thanks

Comment: The title is bad. The fact that you are compiling is not relevant. Calling `gedit` without compiling also reveals the problem. And also calling `gnome-calculator`, `eog`, etc.. I guess it's just every application which uses `libatspi.so.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, which is reported and confirmed for Ubuntu (and hence probably derivatives.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdk-pixbuf/+bug/1193236

Comment: ohk, so there is nothing I can do to get rid of it?

Comment: The bug is filed in Jun, maybe it is fixed in the meanwhile, don't know.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem for years on my debootstrap-installed Xubuntu machines. It's probably a missing package, but google doesn't seem to be helpful this time.

But today I found [this thread](http://ubuntu.aspcode.net/view/635400140124705175657642/couldnt-connect-to-accessibility-bus) which contains the helpful hint:

Adding the line

```
NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
```

to `/etc/environment` (or `export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1` on console) solved the problem for me.